# "alert level"in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

Do the following sentences sound natural or do you have any suggestions to make them sound more natural?

Your Internet usage is at the alert level. You should be careful about it.

Your Internet usage has reached an alarming level. You should be careful about that.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: They don't at all mean the same. Since you asked here, "the alert level: makes no sense while "an alarming level" is wholly understandable.

Could you share what your dictionaries and thesauruses left unclear, and that preferably somewhere such as English Language Learners?

Answer (score 0):

**alert limit**  [TFD](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/alert+limit)

> The maximum position error allowable for a given phase of flight
>   without an alert being raised.

The above is found in phrases ... this one pertaining to navigation. It could be used.  An alarming level sounds better than alert level.  You can use any you see fit.  I would say:

> Your Internet usage is at the alert limit.